Issue with SafeConnector in Vue.js using wagmi
I'm using Vue.js and trying to implement the SafeConnector to install wallet to my dApp by using wagmi. I'm following this documentation.
After installing wagmi core and wagmi connectors, I'm encountering an issue.
Here are the details:
Dependencies:
"@wagmi/connectors": "^5.1.2",
"@wagmi/core": "^2.13.1"

This is my configuration:
<template>
    <h1>{{ connector }}</h1>
</template>

<script setup>

import { SafeConnector } from '@wagmi/core/connectors/safe'
import { mainnet, optimism } from 'viem/chains'

const connector = new SafeConnector({
    chains: [mainnet, optimism],
    options: {
    allowedDomains: [/gnosis-safe.io$/, /app.safe.global$/],
    debug: false
    }
})
</script>

Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?



Per Wagmi's documentation (also here) I believe the correct way to import would be import { safe } from 'wagmi/vue/connectors' or import { safe } from 'wagmi/connectors'.
Could you please try again and confirm it worked? Thanks in advance! 
Best, Louis
